# How to send raw json in request body

Tags: flutter, retrofit

In **Flutter** using **retrofit** package
I need to send json raw object as shown in the postman snapshot.

[image]

I tried to do it by this method but didn't work

```
@override
@POST('/profile')
Future<UserModel> updateUser(@Body() UserModel userModel);
```

this is the request

```
╔╣ Request ║ POST ║ http://206.189.57.118/api/user/profile 

╔ Headers ╟ content-type: application/json ╟ Accept: application/json ╟ Authorization: Bearer 8|LMoB1zivD3O89B7Bv3RQi4zLMeAfTZShmClvWYAt ╟ contentType: application/json ╟ responseType: ResponseType.json ╟ followRedirects: true ╟ connectTimeout: 0 ╟ receiveTimeout: 0 

 ╔ Body ╟ gender: Male ╟ dateOfBirth: 856800000 ╟ maritalStatus: ╟ numChildren: 0 ╟ address: Khanyounis ╟ phone: 123456789 ╟ secondaryPhone: 123456789 ╟ secondaryPhoneRelationShip: ╟ telephone: 123456789 ╟ university: Azhar ╟ faculty: Software Engineering ╟ specialization: Web development ╟ image: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it caused you use camel case on your `UserModel` parameter (ex. `dateOfBirth`, `maritalStatus`) and your back end service try to parse key using underscore type (ex. `date_of_birth`, `marital_status`).

To keep using camel case in your dart file and underscore in json/back end service, you can use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and add `JsonKey` using underscore.
For example

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'user_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserModel {
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_name_ar')
  String firstNameAr;
  @JsonKey(name: 'middle_name_ar')
  String middleNameAr;
  @JsonKey(name: 'last_name_ar')
  String lastNameAr;
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_name_en')
  String firstNameEn;
  @JsonKey(name: 'middle_name_en')
  String middleNameEn;
  @JsonKey(name: 'last_name_en')
  String lastNameEn;
  @JsonKey(name: 'gender')
  String gender;
  @JsonKey(name: 'date_of_birth')
  String dateOfBirth;
  @JsonKey(name: 'marital_status')
  String maritalStatus;
  

  UserModel();
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserModelFromJson(json);
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserModelToJson(this);
}
```

I use this in my project to send raw json data using retrofit and works.